# Django Daphne - Secure websocket connection fails

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, websocket, daphne

I have setup my Django server to run on https mode and the API calls are also working.  I have also configured Daphne which is starting without any problems.  However, when I try to open a secure websocket connection using wss, it fails.

It would be great if I can get any help on this.  Thanks.

### docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  api:
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    command: 'sh -c "./manage.py migrate && python manage.py runsslserver 0.0.0.0:8080"'
    restart: always
    networks:
      - default
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - $HOME/.aws:/root/.aws:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - type: bind
        source: ./docker/cpuinfo_with_fake_speed.txt
        target: /proc/cpuinfo
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db

  daphne:
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: daphne
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    command: 'sh -c "daphne  --ws-protocol [ws, wss] -v 1 -e ssl:8000:privateKey=key.pem:certKey=cert.pem apps.asgi:application"'
    restart: always
    working_dir: /app
    networks:
      - default
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

### asgi.py

```
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter([path('ws/notifications/', NotificationConsumer.as_asgi())])),
    }
)
```

I can see that Daphne service is starting up fine

```
daphne    | 2023-04-28 05:39:32,845 INFO     Starting server at ssl:8000:privateKey=key.pem:certKey=cert.pem
daphne    | 2023-04-28 05:39:32,847 INFO     HTTP/2 support enabled
daphne    | 2023-04-28 05:39:32,847 INFO     Configuring endpoint ssl:8000:privateKey=key.pem:certKey=cert.pem
daphne    | 2023-04-28 05:39:32,891 INFO     Listening on TCP address 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And this is how, I'm trying to open the websocket connection, which fails.

```
wss://localhost:8000/ws/notifications/?userid=x48
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was using a wrong client to test secure websockets.
Chrome extension pie socket works well.